# How to run a JAR file in JavaME SDK 3.0?

Tags: sdk, java-me

I have J2ME SDK 3.0 with NetBeans7.1 
I know you can click a play button on NetBeans to start the emulator and run the main project.
But can I use this emulator to run third-party jar MIDlets?
The emulator is located at:
`C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1\mobility\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0\bin`

I have tried doing:
`emulator <path to jar>`

but the emulator just doesn't run.
What should I do to run a jar that on the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run 3rd party MIDlets in Windows PC you can use [Kemulator](http://www.divshare.com/download/6367812-710) or [MicroEmulator](http://www.microemu.org/)